# Duplicate meta_key and change prefix and then copy meta_value

Tags: php, sql, wordpress, woocommerce, user-roles

Duplicate `meta_key` `_capabilities` and change prefix from `st_pr59t_capabilities` to `wp_capabilities` and then copy `meta_value` of `st_pr59t_capabilities` to `wp_capabilities`

[Take a look at this image: Phpmyadmin Image Illustration](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pv3Ap.jpg)

I am working on creating wordpress sites SITE 1 (`st_pr59t_`) and SITE 2 (`wp_`) that will be accessed by the same set of users.

I have successfuly completed

1) SHARING USERS AND USER META between SITE 1 and SITE 2

2) SHARING LOGIN COOKIES between SITE 1 and SITE 2

So all is fine till here.

Now I want to sync not just users but also user roles (multiple user roles) of all users.

For this I tried the [solution offered HERE](https://kinsta.com/blog/share-logins-wordpress/):

```
function ksu_save_role( $user_id, $role ) {

    $prefix_1 = 'st_pr59t_'; // SITE 1's Table Prefix
    $prefix_2 = 'wp_'; // SITE 2's Table Prefix

    $caps = get_user_meta( $user_id, $prefix_1 . 'capabilities', true );
    $level = get_user_meta( $user_id, $prefix_1 . 'user_level', true );

    if ( $caps ){
        update_user_meta( $user_id, $prefix_2 . 'capabilities', $caps );
    }

    if ( $level ){
        update_user_meta( $user_id, $prefix_2 . 'user_level', $level );
    }
}
add_action( 'set_user_role', 'ksu_save_role', 10, 2 );
```

The above solution works great when only a single user role is assigned to a user. But if a user is assigned multiple user roles then it doesn’t work. I mean, it doesn’t sync all user roles.

After digging through the database I understood that the solution lies in cloning the "`meta_value`" of "`st_pr59t_capabilities`" to "`wp_capabilities`"

Is there a way to copy entire '`meta_value`' for a '`user_id`' from "`st_pr59t__capabilities`" to "`wp_capabilities`"?

[Phpmyadmin Image Illustration](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pv3Ap.jpg)

If we can copy the entire `meta_value` from "`st_pr59t__capabilities`" to "`wp_capabilities`" then all the user roles assigned to a user can be synced.

So what changes need to be done to the above mentioned code to achieve this?

Answer (score 1):

You could try to use [WPDB](https://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/wpdb) methods that will allow to clone user roles, this way:

```
add_action( 'set_user_role', 'ksu_save_role', 10, 2 );
function ksu_save_role( $user_id, $role ) {
    global $wpdb;

    $prefix1 = 'st_pr59t_';
    $prefix2 = 'wp_';

    ## --- USER LEVEL --- ##

    $level = get_user_meta( $user_id, $prefix1 . 'user_level', true );
    if( $level ) {
        update_user_meta( $user_id, $prefix2 . 'user_level', $level );
    }

    ## --- USER ROLES --- ##
    
    $caps = $wpdb->get_var( $wpdb->prepare( "
        SELECT meta_value FROM {$wpdb->prefix}usermeta
        WHERE meta_key = '{$prefix1}capabilities' AND user_id = %d
    ", $user_id ) );

    if( $caps ) {
        $wpdb->query( $wpdb->prepare( "
            UPDATE {$wpdb->prefix}usermeta as um SET meta_value = '%s'
            WHERE um.user_id = %d AND um.meta_key = '{$prefix2}capabilities'
        ", $caps, $user_id ) );
    }
}
```

Code goes in function.php file of your active child theme (or active theme). Tested and works. It should also work for you…

> Edit: **The correct way** is to use `add_user_role` hook instead, replacing:
>
> ```
> add_action( 'set_user_role', 'ksu_save_role', 10, 2 );
> ```
>
> With
>
> ```
> add_action( 'add_user_role', 'ksu_save_role', 10, 2 );
> ```

Comment: I appreciate your efforts to help @LoicTheAztec. Your solution worked when I tried to set (change) a single user role. But when I tried to change multiple user roles it didn't work. I have posted a solution to my problem. Please take a look at it. Thanks!

Comment: @ManjuTalluri It was just about the hook… Very interesting! … I upvote your answer then too…